# Add class in some tags via twig template?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Add class for form tag

I made form like this

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()      
    ->add('name')
    ->add('tel')
    ->add('save','submit')
    ->getForm();
```

in index.html.twig

```
  {{ form_start(form)}}
  {{ form_rest(form)}}
  {{ form_end(form)}}
```

normally it works well

But sometimes I want to add class to form tag
like this

```
<form class=“niceform”>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

How can I do this kind of things via formbuilder and twig template??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

via Doc: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-widget-view-variables

## form_widget(view, variables)

```
{# render a widget, but add a "foo" class to it #}
{{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'foo'}}) }}
```

Comment: THank you I have done. attaching the class to form like this {{ form_start(form,{'attr': {'class': 'niceclass'}}) }} . You gave me the vest reference.

Comment: @whitebear If I helped you solve the problem, tick answer :-) It will tell others that your problem has been resolved.

Comment: SOrry I just forgot to tick the answer, thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you don't like doing these things in Twig, you can also add the class to your formbuilder in php.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()      
    ->add('name', 'text', array(
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'foo'
        )
    ))
    ->add('tel')
    ->add('save','submit')
    ->getForm();
```

Comment: thanks . However it adds the class to 'name' , I want to add the class to 'form' tag itself.I have edited a bit please see article.

Comment: Ah, okay, that was not clear to my. In this case the Twig solution is the correct one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add class foo to form element (tag), then you can use syntax:

```
{{ form(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}
```

If you want to do that for all forms in you website, then it is good practice to use Form themig. Check out file [form_div_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig). Here you can see widgets. Find {% block form_start %} and add class to form element

```
{# your twig file #}
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block form_start -%}
    {% set method = method|upper %}
    {%- if method in ["GET", "POST"] -%}
        {% set form_method = method %}
    {%- else -%}
        {% set form_method = "POST" %}
    {%- endif -%}
    <form name="{{ name }}" class="myclass" method="{{ form_method|lower }}" action="{{ action }}"{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}{% if multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
    {%- if form_method != method -%}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="{{ method }}" />
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_start %}
```

Better choice is to use template in separate file. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming

Comment: THanks,it also helps to understand the twig more deeply.